# Windows has not been removed from dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uninstall

I have removed windows 8.1 from dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 following this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows) . I used the OS uninstaller as described in that tutorial. But still when i boot PC, I see that windows has not been removed, it still works well, **although OS uninstaller confirmed that windows has been removed**.

What should I do to fully remove windows?

Comment: Do you mean even after uninstalling windows from the system, when you select windows from boot menu, you are able to log into windows ?

Comment: yes, exactly its happening

Comment: in Ubutnu, Open Gparted and check, if your windows partition ( that you deleted) is still available and formatted as NTFS. I doubt windows partition was not deleted when you tried to remove it

Comment: somehow windows removed, i dont know how? thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

You can try this tutorial found at lifehacker at [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-or-linux-after-dual-booting-508710422).

> 1)    Insert a live CD or USB for your Linux distribution and start up
>   its partition manager (like Gparted). Find your Windows partition in
>   Gparted's menu—it'll be listed as an NTFS drive.
>
> 2)    Right-click on that Windows partition and choose "Delete" from
>   the menu. Your machine may have other Windows-related partitions as
>   well, like "System Reserved" and recovery partitions. If you want, you
>   can delete these as well (but make sure you have recovery discs handy
>   if you're going to delete a recovery partition).
>
> 3)    Right-click on your Linux partition and choose "Resize/Move."
>   Resize it so it takes up the rest of the now-free space on your drive.
>
> 4)    Click the "Apply All Operations" button in the toolbar to
>   perform the selected tasks. It may give you a warning saying that your
>   computer may not boot, but with most Linux instalations this shouldn't
>   be a problem (though if it is, check out this article to fix it). This
>   process may take some time, so let it be!
>
> When it finishes, you should have a hard drive with nothing but Linux
>   on it. Your boot menu will still have some Windows entries, and it'll
>   work fine if you leave them there, but if you want to clean things up,
>   just open up a Terminal in Linux and run:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> to remove them.

Comment: I am greatefull to u for cooperation, but in this moment neither i have a CD nor a usb drive,  I just have internet connection.

Comment: You can try deleting partition containing windows using gparted from your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: partho, you should be able to skip over the live cd/usb part of the process.

Comment: Glad to hear it. :) Go ahead and accept my answer then, so that future visitors may find it helpful.